# Which one of the sentences is type 1 conditional and which one is type 0?

Tags: grammar, conditionals

Which one of the following sentences in bold is type 1 conditional 1 and which one is type 0 in the following examples?

Example 1

A: There’s something wrong with my keyboard.

B: What’s wrong?

A: I can’t refresh the webpage. **Even if I press F5, I still can’t refresh it.**

Example 2

A: I can't refresh my webpage.

B: Have you tried pressing F5?

A: There's something wrong with the internet, not the keyboard. I haven't even bothered to try it. **Even if I press F5, I still can't refresh the webpage.**

I think the first one sounds like a type 0 because it’s about situations that happen repeatedly; on the other hand, I think the second one is a type 1 because it’s talking about a specific future result (even if I press the button, there won’t be any opportunities of the pages being successfully refreshed.)

I am not sure, so I want to know why you guys think about my choice.

Comment: Hello Chien,  You haven't told us what your difficulty is here.  Please edit to clarify why you find this task hard.  I've voted to close as "needs details" because you haven't explained what your question is, you've only told us what your teacher's question is.

Comment: Already edited it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the lies of English teachers is that there are 4 "types" of conditional.  Note that in schools in England and the US, children aren't taught this in their English lessons, this is something that only non-natives speakers will get taught.

The point of teaching the four types is to note that the past tense in a conditional doesn't refer to past time, and to give a simple set of rules.  Actual use is more complicated.

The structure and meaning of your two examples is identical. The use of the pronoun "it" doesn't change the meaning in the slightest.  Both have a "type 0" structure.  But the meaning is a hypothetical and the probable outcome.

The four types are a framework for learning, not a true fact about English grammar.  They are like training wheels for your bike; useful at first, but you need to move on.
If you are a B or C level speaker of English, you should probably move on from thinking about the four types of conditional.  There are lots of utterances that simply don't fit.